# How does Chrome know my geolocation?

Tags: html, google-chrome, geolocation

Chrome seems to be very accurate in detecting my location. How does it do it? Can you point me to the source code?

Comment: I think they use your IP and their huge knowledge (data) about the Internet.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Geolocation can be calculated based on:

1. GPS (if available)
2. Available wi-fi networks and signal strengths
3. Available cell towers and signal strengths
4. IP Address lookup

See the [W3C Geolocaton API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) and [Google Gears API](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/api_geolocation.html) (which Chrome's/W3C Geolocation API is based on).

[Chromium's geolocation source code](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/browser/geolocation/) can be viewed online.

Comment: +1 Good answer and well formatted. You are pointing to Google Gears Source Code though not Chrome's although it's probably pretty much identical for the location providers.

Comment: Bonus question: What are the pros/cons of using inbuilt Geolocation vs Googles Geolocation API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro

Answer (score 8):

Your location can be obtain using different services and hardware available on your device. The most common ones are: GPS, wifi information, cell towers. Alternatively there is also IP lookup, however this is not very accurate and does not involve anything special on your device.

In your case most likely information about your wifi network was used. There are huge databases which connect wifi networks to a location, created by cars with GPS & Wifi (e.g. Google Street View cars). The transmission from your computer to the server is done according to [W3C Geolocation API Specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/), which is part of HTML5.

Chrome Source for this?
[Here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#h0RrPvyPu-c/chrome/browser/geolocation/location_provider.h&q=Geolocation%20package:src.chromium.org/svn/trunk) is a entry point to start off from. Or if you prefer the old fashioned file browser: http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome/browser/geolocation/

Implementation files for localization via wifi:

- wifi_data_provider_mac.cc
- wifi_data_provider_linux.cc
- wifi_data_provider_win.cc

Answer (score 0):

They look at several things:
 -> The unique identifiers (SSID) of wireless networks at your location and signal strengths.
 -> IP address (your public IP address)
 -> GPS (if available)
 -> Mobile network location data (if available)

Answer (score 0):

a browser on a pc does not have a gps, however it has an external ip address (usually the router's external ip address). if other components behind the same router has a gps - this pins location to that ip address and via location services attaches this location to the browser.

Answer (score -1):

I think they use your IP address and a [geolocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation) service like http://www.ip2location.com/ or (more likely) their own [geolocation database](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_database.php)/service)

Comment: Chrome actually reads what Wi-Fi networks are around you, and submits their SSIDs to Google, which returns an approximate address. It can be spooky accurate where Google has driven their Street View cars, even if your dekstop/laptop doesn't have a GPS sensor.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Wi-Fi may be only one part of the determination process. Furthermore you must differ between mobile and desktop versions of Chrome! I think Chrome is mainly using the HTML5 Geolocation API where Wi-Fi is only one part.

Answer (score -2):

Recently i worked on HTML 5 Geo-location assignment. Its supported in all modern browsers (IE9, Safari, FF, Opera).
But when I came to Chrome its not supported. I spent several hours in fixing this.
Finally I found a a solution:

The geolocation in Chrome is turned off by default. To activate it, users must go to their Chrome shortcut and add `--enable-geolocation` to the end of the target line, under the Shortcut tab.

Comment: That is not true.  Or more accurately, your answer was posted in 2012 and it hasn't been true in years.  Chrome 17/18 certainly has geolocation enabled by default.

Comment: This is scary! Geolocation being as precise as it is (down to wi-fi/street address), does it mean that every web server I access now knows my street address, within a couple of houses?

Comment: No, as user permission is required before geolocation data is given to a website. This has been true since this answer was posted.