# How does a browser gather GPS information?

Tags: html, geolocation, gps

I'm currently writing a web app which uses the geolocation feature of browsers. Last week I moved to a new city, but as I'm testing my app I noticed that the Browser continues to provide GPS location for the old address.

In an effort to "refresh" this information, I am asking how that is determined? I am using my same router, same laptop, and same browser. Which of these (if not all, or if any) is holding on to that information?

Comment: Actually, I have tested in more than one browser, and it is the same for both. So I think I can rule out the browser itself holding on to that data.

Comment: Unless your laptop is equipped with some sort of GPS receiver, it isn't providing any GPS information at all...

Comment: That depends on the browser. The [geolocation specification](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) doesn't say anything about how browsers are supposed to implement it.

Comment: This has been answered in another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668304/how-does-google-calculate-my-location-on-a-desktop

Comment: So it is the router. Thanks @Greg. I searched 5 different ways and never found a similar question.

Comment: @Jason - here's [another similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378061/how-browser-gets-gps-data-from-a-computer) and the question pointed by Greg has the best answer.