# How is Chrome on my laptop able to provide such freakishly precise geolocation?

Tags: javascript, geolocation

My code:
           var x = document.getElementById("demo");

```
    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else {
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
        x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
                "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude +
                "<br>More or less"  + position.accuracy + "meters";

    }
```

Position.accuracy is 96 meters (which is, to me, surprising enough), but the position itself is spot on. Literally, it hits home. And I always thought laptops only geolocate by IP address, which should offer the accuracy of a couple of miles? What's the source of this precise info?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Chrome know my geolocation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633621/how-does-chrome-know-my-geolocation)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the original source of the information comes from mobile devices like smartphones. Google and other companies have a database of wireless routers with GPS information. This information can be harvested by mobile devices that have transmitted the location of your wireless router to google in the past.  IOS does this as well.

For example. If I walk next to some wireless router with my IOS device it will pick up the wireless router (not fully connecting though) and will note the GPS location and then send this to Apple. Now Apple now knows the location of that wireless router. This is the same for Android devices and Google.

see:

- See "HOW IS APPLE COLLECTING GEODATA?" in
  http://www.wired.com/2011/04/apple-iphone-tracking/
- or, http://www.theguardian.com/technology/blog/2011/apr/25/google-router-map-exposed

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp reference about geoLocation and google map API.]
They are using getCurrentPosition() for fetch the current position of the user and the showPosition() returns longitude and latitude to the users.getCurrentPosition() always give you a precise location.