# Geolocation coordinate is not exactly correct location

Tags: javascript

I use Geolocation API like this :

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError); 
}
function showPosition(position) {                     
var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
var longitude =position.coords.longitude;
}
```

but coordinates is not exactly correct.mean is not show my real location.
It is approximately 20-30 meter away from my real place.
I change code :

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError,{
                 enableHighAccuracy: true,
                 timeout: 10 * 1000, // 5 seconds
                 maximumAge: 0
}); 
}
function showPosition(position) {                     
var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
var longitude =position.coords.longitude;
}
```

but it still don't show correct real location.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a mobile or desktop to test this implementation?

Because desktops do not have GPS capability. So it gets your **approximately** location using others methods.

Give a look here [How does Chrome know my geolocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633621/how-does-chrome-know-my-geolocation)

Comment: Thanks , I use only mobile devices and test in some phones like samsung j5, huawei Honor 3C, Xiaomi redmi 9s. GPS is On and Access is granted. but not returned true location.